# OracleBulkCopy Performance

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, bulk

My C# .NET app writes millions of records to a temp table using OracleBulkCopy. Every time the app has 20000 records or more in memory it call OracleBulkCopy to write all of them in a single batch (I am using batch size = 0). At the beginning the table is empty and it takes just 2 seconds to write the whole batch. During the process the time for writing the batch increases. After 2.000.000 records each call takes almost 25 seconds. I am using the default options of OracleBulkCopy. Doing some tests when the table reaches 40.000.000 it takes almost 3 minutes to write 20.000 records.

I would like to know if there is any recommendation (I couldn't find anything about it) in order to maintain an almost constant time for each call. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do you have some insert triggers on this table?

Comment: No, nothing. Not even a primary key. And table is set for no logging.

Comment: What exactly does "temp" table mean? A global temporary table?

Comment: A "temp" table means a table we use to load those records that later are inserted in another table using insert from select. It is faster to insert first in this "temp" table which is empty than to insert directly in the definitive table. It is not a temporary table. It is just another table of our database that we use as an intermediary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like strange behaviour.  Have you traced the database session doing the inserts to see what it is waiting on?

```
ALTER SESSION SET timed_statistics=TRUE;
ALTER SESSION SET max_dump_file_size=UNLIMITED;
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
```

99 times out of 100, the trace results will point you at the problem in these strange slow down cases.

Comment: The problem was the primary key. I was sure the table was created without a primary key. Using the trace file we observed thousands of sequential read on the primary key. Removing it resulted in an almost constant time of 0.8 seconds per batch.

Comment: Glad you found it and the SQL Trace found yet another problem. If things go slow, SQL Trace should always be the first thing to try.